# HPONCFG use variable as input instead file?

Tags: scripting, hp, ilo

I'm currently writing a script to get all the embedded health of an ILO. 
What I want is to avoid to create file, so I've create my xml request but I tried with no success with the /i parameter of HPONCFG :-(

Does anyone have successfully used a input stream instead of a xml file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution that I posted [to this forum](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-remote-lights-out-mgmt-iLO/HPONCFG-i-use-and-examples/td-p/5681979).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how you're executing the command? The "/i" indicates that you're using Windows. In Linux, the approach is to use `hponcfg -i`. The XML input stream would be piped into the command. I believe the same applies to Windows scripting.

Comment: Hi ewwhite, I'm in Windows and execute a vbscript like that : Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.Exec ("cmd /c " & requestXML & " | X:\Tools\iLo\hponcfg /i") requestXML is my string variable                                                                                                                                When I execute manually the command hponcfg /i, I can copy paste the XML press return and I need to press also CTRL+C to obtain result